# Standalone jar to log on jboss's log4j

Tags: java, log4j

Is it possible log on the same log as a deployed jboss app from a standalone jar?

This both the jboss app and the standalone are using log4j.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that it is possible, but in some cases, the standalone app will have to have the jboss-common-client.jar because generally the jboss log4j uses some of its classes.

The trick was in setting the -Dlog4j.configuration vm argument to point to the same log4j.xml than jboss's and make sure the standalone app does also start with the parameter that is used in the jboss log4j configuration (generally jboss.server.home.dir so that its logs are written in the same place.